# How to add images in codeigniter using Bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have started designing a website using codeigniter tutorial from tuts plus and encountered problem on how to add carousel images using Bootstrap in codeigniter. My images are found at `/images/...`

How can I solve this problem?

```
<div class="intro-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class=" t">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <div id="artcoursel" class="carousel slide">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <img src= "images/test-1.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing a `"` before `images/test-1.png` for starters

Comment: Thank you the reason is not that. I forget it when I am posting here.

Comment: what problem are you having? is the image not showing up? is it not displaying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<img src=<?php echo base_url('images/test-1.png')?>>
```